# Any Way to Print to the Console with Color in AppleScript?

Tags: objective-c, colors, console, applescript, ansi-escape

In Objective-C, one can print color to the console using the following code:

```
NSLog(@"\e[1;31mHere is red text!\e[m Here's normal text");
```

However, if I were to attempt to print the same string using AppleScript's `log`, I would get `Expected “"” but found unknown token. (-2741)`. Is there any way to print color using AppleScript or was such a capability simply never included?

Thanks.

Comment: The backslash is used as an escape character, so to use it in a string it must also be escaped.  ANSI colors can be used in a shell, but the Script Editor `log` command doesn't use them.

Comment: @red_menace, Actually, the first thing that I tried was to escape the escape character. Unfortunately, that prints the escape sequence to the console literally, not color.

Comment: No one will know what you've tried unless you tell them.  Something like `tell application "Terminal" to do script "printf " & quoted form of "\\e[1;31mHere is red text!\\e[m Here's normal text"` prints colors in the Terminal.

Comment: Works, but unfortunately restricts the output to the "Terminal" app, which may not necessarily always be what's being used to run the script. I appreciate your suggestions, though!